# What is an Async run loop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, datastore

I'm reading an architecture document and I stumbled on the term **Async Run Loops** and how [NDB](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb) provides better Async run loops. However, I have been unable to find any explanation of the concept anywhere. Can someone please explain what it means.

Comment: can you link to where you read it / where they talked about it? It sounds like they may be talking about how in `ndb` you can set up tasklets which can run asynchronously

Comment: It's an internal document.